# Not able to solve KlockWork Buffer Overflow error

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, static-analysis, klocwork

I am not able to figure out the solution for this KlockWork issue.

KlockWork is showing ABV.GENERAL (1:P1) Defer for the following code

```
void fun1(uint32_t size)
{
  if(size > 256)
  {
    return;
  }
  uint32_t *arr = (uint32_t *)malloc(size * sizeof(uint32_t));
  if(arr == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }
  memset(arr, 0, size * sizeof(uint32_t)); 
  fun2(arr, size);
  free(arr);
}

void fun2(uint32_t *arr, uint32_t size)
{
  uint32_t i = 0;
  if(size > 256)
  {
    return;
  }
  while( i < size )
  {
    arr[i] = i;
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

> Error: Array 'arr' of size 'size*4' may use index values(s) min(size+(-1), 255)..min(size+(-1), 255)

Please suggest some ways to avoid this error.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe its something related to types. Variable size is once int, once uint32_t

Comment: sorry my bad.. the argument size passed to fun1 is also uint32..

Comment: NEVER!!! NEVER cast the result value of `malloc`.  It's a legacy use that hides several possible mistakes (as the one you made of not including `<stdlib.h>`, for example)  It predates from the times when there was no `void` type in C.  You should not have to use the cast if you had included properly the `<stdlib.h>` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you lack one of these header files, or the forward function prototype for the `fun2` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun2(uint32_t*arr, uint32_t size);
```

I have compiled your code prepending all this stuff, and no warnings or errors got.  Plus what I have told you in the comments to your question.